# ckeditor is rendering the text in the editor itself in bold but the code produced is correct

Tags: ckeditor

Everything was fine until I went to my project this morning to find the ckeditor rendering the text in the editor itself in bold, but the code produced is correct. Image sample below:

[image]

But this is the code the editor saves to the database which is correct:

```
<p>A person recently started a thread on Facebook asking why we identify our calling&nbsp;in the government of God: whether apostle, prophet, evangelist, pastor, or teacher. This question is shared by many as the church observes God again raising up His spiritual government. I thought that a teaching on the subject would be</p>
```

If I highlight and bold the text as shown below:

[image]

the editor will generate the correct code:

```
<p>A person recently started a thread on Facebook asking why we identify our calling&nbsp;in the government of God: whether apostle, prophet, evangelist, pastor, or teacher. This question is shared by many as the church observes God again raising up His spiritual government.</p><p></p><p><strong>I thought that a teaching on the subject would be</strong></p>
```

The problem is the user cannot tell what they have made bold and what is not bold.

I am not sure what has happened... I have not touched anything related to the ckeditor code/css. Assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ISSUE RESOLVED:

It was a simple programming error in the code above. I had simply left a backslash out of a closing `</b>` in the code above the ckEditor.